# using getline to get multiple lines from a file and input them in different arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, getline

I'm trying to do a simple `getline` from a filestream and then store the different input into different arrays.

The input file is something like this.

> Course Of Sales Time,Price ($),Volume,Value ($),Condition 10/10/2013
>   04:57:27 PM,5.81,5000,29050.00,LT XT 10/10/2013 04:48:05
>   PM,5.81,62728,364449.68,SX XT 10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,.00,0,.00,

Note that the first two lines are redundant and should be ignored. All data should be stored in their respective arrays like time[i], price[i].

```
string datefield;
int count = 0;
string date[5000];
float pricefield;
float price [5000];
int volume[5000];
float value[5000];
string condition[5000];
int i = 0;

while (!infile.eof()) {
    count++;
    getline(infile,datefield);
    while (count >= 2) {
        getline(infile,date[i], ',');
        infile  >> price[i] >> volume[i];
        i++;
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, no input is going into `volume[i].`

Comment: First: [`while (!infile.eof())` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). You never check a single extraction in this code for validity before assuming it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't put `eof()` in the `while` condition. It's wrong! Check out: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong). To work out, you can change

   ```
   while (!infile.eof()) {
       count++;
       getline(infile,datefield);
       ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   while (getline(infile,datefield)) {
       count++;
       ...
   ```
2. You should be very careful in the data reading step. For `",.00,0,.00,"`, as there is no spaces within it, thus `>> price[i] >> volume[i]` will try to read all these content to `price[i]`. No content will be read into `volume[i]`. To work out, you can first read this part to a `string` and then read the data from it by splitting. Or replace all `','` to spaces and then put it into a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), then you can use `>> price[i] >> volume[i]` correctly.